# Estimate amount spent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle, estimation

I am reading the following simple problem on rounding.

> 10 people ordered calculators.
> The least expensive was \$19.95 and the
> most expensive \$39.95 Half ordered a \$29.95 calculator.
> Select the
> best estimate of the amount spent:
> a) \$240
> b) \$310
> c) \$345
> d) \$355

My approach:
The rest of the 5 could have ordered either \$20 or \$40 or \$10
So we have (on top of the $5$ that the problem mentions they bought the \$30 calculator)
$150 + 5 * 20 = 250$
or
$150 + 5 * 40 = 350$
or
$150 + 5 * 30 = 300$

So we get an average of 250 + 350 + 300 = \$900 which divided by 3 gives \$300
That is not part of the options though and the solution states that the correct answer is **b**

What am I messing up here?

Comment: I don't think there is enough information.  I guess we are told that five of the people paid $29.95$, that at least one paid $19.95$ and that at least one paid $39.95$ which leaves three people unaccounted for.  No way to answer the question without knowing something about them.

Comment: @lulu: I see that $150 + 2*20 + 3*40 = 310$ i.e. split the rest of the 5 into $floor(2.5)$ and $ceil(2.5)$ but is there such a convention?

Comment: All I can see is that we know the total is at least  $269.5$ and at most $329.5$ but I see no way to settle on a number in between them.  Of course you could take an average, getting $299.5$ if you want to.

Comment: @lulu: How are you getting the $269.5 - 329.5$ range? I thought the min would be $150 + 100 = 250$

Comment: I get the lower range by assuming that four people spend $19.95$ and I get the upper range by assuming that four people spend $39.95$

Comment: @lulu: Why 4 and not 5?

Comment: It is assumed that "the least expensive" in the question refers to the least expensive of the 10 calculators that were actually ordered, and similarly for the most expensive. So there is at least one of each of those.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis:Ah I misread that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

To round things out, let $$A=20\quad B=30\quad C=40$$

Assuming some kind of bell-curve in purchasing, we have

$$2A+5B+2C+??=40+150+ 80+??=270+??$$

Given that this is already above the $240$-estimate where $??=-30$, we must assume that $??=40$ and the sum $$270+??=310$$

Comment: Why $2A$ and $2C$?

Comment: @Jim I'm just thinking how $\big\lfloor\frac{5}{2}\big\rfloor=2$ of remaining people would by the cheep model $(2A)$ and $\big\lfloor\frac{5}{2}\big\rfloor=2$ would buy the expensive model $(2C)$ if they didn't buy the middle-prices one.